# Data from mongoDB is not loading on my site

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mern, atlas

I am new to web development and i made this E-commerce website with MERN few months ago as my first big project and it worked fine but now my product images,categories and other user and admin data is not loading. I cant login with previously created accounts and cant register new accounts but vs code terminal says db is connected and shows no error.

this is my collection on atlas
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPhUm.png)

Here is the code for my mongo connection.

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import colors from "colors";
mongoose.set('strictQuery', false);
const connectDB = async () => {
  try {
    const conn = await mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://id:<pass>@cluster0.3mqorsq.mongodb.net/test");
    console.log(
      `Conneted To Mongodb Databse ${conn.connection.host}`.bgMagenta.white
    );
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(`Errro in Mongodb ${error}`.bgRed.white);
  }
};

export default connectDB;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to add username and password as well

```
const conn = await mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://username:password@cluster0.3mqorsq.mongodb.net/test");
```

Comment: Added them in my code. I used id and pass here to hide actual credentials.